# Could not connect: Access denied for user 'user'@'rs107.nsresponse.com' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, cpanel

few day back my hosting server was goes down. so all my website stop working,i am usig cpanel for setting password and privileges to the user.
the i have changd mysql username and password and also set all privilleges to that user  asd also set new passwrod to my websites's config file but still not working website .

while access it on browser it gives me error .

Comment: I am guessing you have not setup the permissions correctly.

Comment: checked all the permission. i have set all the permission throught the cpanel.

Comment: Check them again then, you can _only_ be getting that error because something is not correct.

Comment: i have just checked there is no issue. i have set all privilleges to this user

Comment: If there were no issue, it would be working.....

Comment: :( but it does not. checking since last two days

Comment: Please visit the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future reference.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using remote mysql you need to enable it on cPanel

Comment: No it wouldn't. You would get a failed to connect message in that case, not an access denied message

Comment: what to do with my problem @Dezza